# Remove categories having count as 0 in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove categories having count as 0 after pandas value_counts function()

My data is as follows:

```
categories: 
Index(['Average', 'Good',  'Poor', ,'VeryGood', 'VeryPoor'],
  dtype='object')

 Output of value counts:

  score     Frequency
   VG        21
   G         15
   A         63
   P         27
   VP        0
```

My result should be as

```
  score     Frequency
   VG        21
   G         15
   A         63
   P         27
```

I want to store this in a dataframe and plot bargraph of this. I don't want to show VP in graph as it's count is 0 and hence eliminate that category

My code:

```
          quality_scores=quality.SCORE.value_counts()
          quality_scores=pd.Series.to_frame(quality_scores)
          quality_scores=quality_scores.rename(columns={'SCORE': 
            'Frequency'})
          quality_scores['Score']=quality_scores.index
          quality_scores=quality_scores.reset_index(drop=True)


          quality_scores = quality_scores[quality_scores.Frequency != 0]
          quality_scores
```

I am editing the answer based on the comments:

I got the answers correct when I print the dataframe. However, when I check categories using quality_scores['Score'].cat.categories, I still see the VP  category which shouldn't be displayed.

Also, in the graph, I don't expect to see the VP category but its displayed on axis.

The following is code for the graph:

```
           plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))

           quality_graph=sns.barplot(y=quality_scores["Frequency"],
           x=quality_scores["Score"])

           quality_graph.set_xlabel('Frequency')

           quality_graph.set_title('Score Distribution of Quality 
           Measure:',fontsize=25)

           plt.savefig('graphs\\Quality_Measure.png')
```

If you could see there are many blank categories on the graph. This are not actually present in the quality_scores dataframe. 
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing now, i.e. `quality_scores = quality_scores[quality_scores.Frequency != 0]` ?

Comment: i didn't get you.

Comment: In your question, you say you want to filter out frequency == 0. Isn't that what you're doing already?

Comment: yes but its not working. when i plot the grapg it still shows the VP with count 0

Comment: Could you add to your question 1) sample code, and 2) the result you're getting that you're not expecting? What is the value of quality_scores after you run the second-to-last line in your code, "quality_scores = quality_scores[quality_scores.Frequency != 0]"?

Comment: Hello David, can you please the edited answer again

Comment: It's the code and data regarding quality_scores that I want to see.

Comment: I  have shared the actual code with you already.

Comment: You might look at this article, "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example," at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

Use [`remove_unused_categories()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.remove_unused_categories.html)

```py
df.col_name = df.col_name.cat.remove_unused_categories()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `VP` is still an attribute of that Series. Since pandas 0.23 you can pass `observed=True` into your `groupby` to remove unobserved categories from your data:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

Remember that case matters: "SCORE" and "Score" are not the same. You created two columns, one called "SCORE" and the other called "Score".

I ran the following code, and it worked as expected.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
grades = ['VG','G','A','P','VP']
counts = [21,15,63,27,0] 

d = { 'Score' : grades, 'Frequency': counts }
quality_scores = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
quality_scores=quality_scores.reset_index(drop=True)
quality_scores = quality_scores[quality_scores.Frequency != 0]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
quality_graph=sns.barplot(y=quality_scores['Frequency'], x=quality_scores['Score'])
quality_graph.set_xlabel('Frequency')
quality_graph.set_title('Score Distribution of Quality Measure:',fontsize=25)
plt.savefig('Quality_Measure.png')
```